# Want to enable two different functions for 2 clicks of a same button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a button in angular which is populated inside a table using ng-repeat.

My table is :

```
<div class="widget-content" ng-controller="getAllBenchersController">

                <table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in data | filter: testFilter">

                        <td data-title="'#'">{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td data-title="'Select Account'">
                            <select>
                                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                                <option id="selectedLocked">Blocked</option>
                                <option id="selectedBilled">Billed<//option>
                                <option id="selectedShadow">Shadow</option>
                                <option id="selectedOnNotice">OnNotice</option>
                                <option id="selectedPOC">POC</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <a><button class="btn  btn-success">Reserve</button></a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
```

I also want to hide the dropdown list populated in the table on page load.
Upon first button click, I want the dropdown list to get displayed.
Upon, second click of the same button, I need to run a function with another purpose.

I am new to Angular and have no clue how to achieve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: look into `ng-click="if(!dropdown_showing){show_dropdown()}else{do_something_else()}`

Comment: How to hide that dropdown on page load?

Comment: you may want to look at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial just use `ng-cloak` and `ng-show` or `ng-hide`

Comment: Im getting documentation on manipulating DIV. can i do the same on a <td>>

Comment: as I said, read the tutorials. Yes, you can, quote, `Usage: as attribute: <ANY
  ng-if="expression">...</ANY>`